# Windows script to delete folder

Tags: windows, scripting, directory

I need to have windows script to delete folder & files those are older by x days than the last modified folder, So if there are only the folders modified by same date then no folder should be deleted, else if there is any folder older by x days than last modified folder date needs to be deleted.

Could someone please response on it?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at powershell.

Comment: Could someone share the exact script with me